# Facebook Credits Api implementation

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-credits

I have used the github sample (https://github.com/facebook/credits-api-sample) and used everything and it gives me this error: There Was a Problem Processing Your Payment
I updated my app id and secret by the way. 
everything I do just gives me an error. I have the callback set to callback.php, i have myself as a test user, I have registered my company and set it, i enabled requests 2.0, sandbox mode is disabled.
I have no idea what the problem is.

I hate their documentation on their site, and it would be nice if they had more examples that actually worked.

if anyone can tell me what my error is, or provide me with a working callback and example, that would be exceptional.

Thanks

Comment: I tried to find the error, and my app has not been whitelisted to use the credits yet, so hopefully soon it will be. then i'll see if it works or not.